# MySQL Group By Order and Count(Distinct)

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, odbc, distinct

What is the best way to think about the Group By function in MySQL?

I am writing a MySQL query to pull data through an ODBC connection in a pivot table in Excel so that users can easily access the data.

For example, I have:

```
Select 
statistic_date,
week(statistic_date,4),
year(statistic_date),
Emp_ID,
count(distict Emp_ID),
Site
Cost_Center
```

I'm trying to count the number of unique employees we have by site by week. The problem I'm running into is around year end, the calendar years don't always match up so it is important to have them by date so that I can manually filter down to the correct dates using a pivot table (2013/2014 had a week were we had to add week 53 + week 1).

I'm experimenting by using different group by statements but I'm not sure how the order matters and what changes when I switch them around.

i.e.

```
Group by week(statistic_date,4), Site, Cost_Center, Emp_ID
```

vs

```
Group by Site, Cost_Center, week(statistic_date,4), Emp_ID
```

Other things to note:

-Employees can work any number of days. Some are working 4 x 10's, others 5 x 8's with possibly a 6th day if they sign up for OT. If I sum the counts by week, I get anywhere between 3-7 per Emp_ID. I'm hoping to get 1 for the week.

-There are different pay code per employee so the distinct count helps when we are looking by day (VTO = Voluntary Time Off, OT = Over Time, LOA = Leave of Absence, etc). The distinct count will show me 1, where often times I will have 2-3 for the same emp in the same day (hits 40 hours and starts accruing OT then takes VTO or uses personal time in the same day).

I'm starting with a query I wrote to understand our paid hours by week. I'm trying to adapt it for this application. Actual code is below:

```
SELECT
 dkh.STATISTIC_DATE AS 'Date'
,week(dkh.STATISTIC_DATE,4) as 'Week'
,month(dkh.STATISTIC_DATE) as 'Month'
,year(dkh.STATISTIC_DATE) as 'Year'
,dkh.SITE AS 'Site ID Short'
,aep.LOC_DESCR as 'Site Name'
,dkh.EMPLOYEE_ID AS 'Employee ID'
,count(distinct dkh.EMPLOYEE_ID) AS 'Distinct Employee ID'
,aep.NAME AS 'Employee Name'
,aep.BUSINESS_TITLE AS 'Business_Ttile'
,aep.SPRVSR_NAME AS 'Manager'
,SUBSTR(aep.DEPTID,1,4) AS 'Cost_Center'
,dkh.PAY_CODE
,dkh.PAY_CODE_SHORT
,dkh.HOURS

FROM metrics.DAT_KRONOS_HOURS dkh

JOIN metrics.EMPLOYEES_PUBLIC aep
ON aep.SNAPSHOT_DATE = SUBDATE(dkh.STATISTIC_DATE, DAYOFWEEK(dkh.STATISTIC_DATE) + 1)
AND aep.EMPLID = dkh.EMPLOYEE_ID

WHERE dkh.STATISTIC_DATE BETWEEN  adddate(now(), interval -1 year) AND DATE(now())

group by dkh.SITE, SUBSTR(aep.DEPTID,1,4), week(dkh.STATISTIC_DATE,4), dkh.STATISTIC_DATE, dkh.EMPLOYEE_ID
```

Comment: Why do you have a `group by` in this query if you have no aggregation functions in the `select`?

Answer (score 0):

The order you use in group by doesn't matter. Each unique combination of the values gets a group of its own. Selecting columns you don't group by gives you somewhat arbitrary results; you'd probably want to use some aggregation function on them, such as SUM to get the group total.

Grouping by values you derive from other values that you already use in group by, like below, isn't very useful.

```
week(dkh.STATISTIC_DATE,4), dkh.STATISTIC_DATE
```

If two rows have different weeks, they'll also have different dates, right?

Comment: I also feel like that, but is there not a way to do this? I mean Group by SITE under that Group by Year under that Group by week and so on.

Comment: The result you get is "flat", you can't get results "under" other results. You can order the results by site, year,  and week.

Comment: So if I'm trying to find how many unique employees were on our roster in any given week (had hours listed under any of the paycodes; VTO, OT, Reg, LOA, etc), how would I count distinct employees per week?